# Access Denied for DVWA in Xampp running in Backtrack 5 r3

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, backtrack-linux

Installed `Xampp` in Backtrack 5 r3. I wanted to use Damn Vulnerable Web App through it. But after copying `DVWA` files to local host i.e `XAMPP`, when i try to access by going to   `120.0.0.1/dvwa` its showing 403 error.
I got a `.htaccess` file in `DVWA` folder.  I saw below codes.

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
</Limit>
```

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add allow from your IP of your BT machine

Example:

allow from 192.168.0.0/16

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error, you need to do:

```
chmod -R 755 dvwa/
```

You now should have the permission to access the folder.